# Knockout.js boolean not updating

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm attempting to enable / disable an input field.

```
<input data-bind="disable: chatDisabled" id="send-message" type="textarea" class="input-area" value="">
```

And my knockoutJS

```
function MessagesViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:4000');

    self.messages = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.chatSend = ko.observable();
    self.questionChoice = ko.observable();
    self.chatDisabled = ko.observable(false);


    socket.on('receiveMessages', function(data) {
        self.messages(data.messages);
        var last = data.messages[data.messages.length-1];
        self.chatDisabled = last.enforce || false;
        scrollToBottom();
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new MessagesViewModel());
```

I've managed to get other parts working such as having a list of messages on the screen populate when the array is updated. However for the life of me I cannot get the input to toggle between disabled / enabled when it is changed within `socket.on(`

`self.messages(` updates corrected so why does `self.chatDisabled` not? (To be clear the variable JS side is updated however it the data-bind is not.

Comment: `self.chatDisabled(last.enforce || false;)`?

Comment: @peinearydevelopment is correct, you are changing the value of chatDisabled to equal last.enforce || false instead of updating the contents of the observable.

Comment: AH I'm an idiot, thank you /facepalm

Comment: @peinearydevelopment if you put that as the answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
self.chatDisabled(last.enforce || false);
```

You were assigning a new value to your property instead of updating the observable value.